# WPF menu (menu items) based on DLLs (modules)

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism

I am trying to show menu based on the DLLs (Modules loaded dynamically from DLLs). I have tried to search online and most of the sources has pointed to use prism but I have no experience with Prism hence looking for help.

Below is the scenario :

I have normal customers and premium customer for a wpf application.
For premium customers I will be adding more features in future and will provide only newly developed DLLs (not the entire application).

For normal customers I will provide only selected DLLs for trial or may be paid.

So how do we load the menu based on those DLLs.

Any small example or reference would be very helpful.

Comment: You could just ship two versions of the product... But if you really need to load features from dlls then MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Any reference you can help with? I could find examples showing how to load modules based on dlls but could not find anything on how to manipulate the menu for the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Prism's modules are for. You encapsulate functionality in an assembly and include an `IModule` implementation that describes the contents. The module-loading mechanism works independent of the dependency injection container used, supporting e.g. Unity, Ninject or Autofac (MEF is *not* a dependency injection container but rather a plugin framework).

Depending on your application, populating the menu from the loaded modules could be as simple as having each module register some menu items in your menu region.

Comment: Can you please help with an example? I got references on how to load the modules dynamically but how do I add items to menu and bind it to UI. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This really depends on your app - how's your menu built? If, for example, you've got an `ItemsControl` as menu region, just make each module register its menu items for that region (`IRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion`).

Comment: Thanks. Currently the application is static and uses Menu control. It is not using Prism. I will try to implement the point mentioned and update this post with the code once it is done.